# Flutter Navigation rail unselected text color not showing

Tags: flutter

I am using Navigation rail in my app all is working fine but problem is only the active naigation text is showing color and others are invisible i try to change the color but its not working

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          NavigationRail(
            backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
            groupAlignment: 1,
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.selected,
            unselectedLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,),
            selectedLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),

            destinations: [
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
                label: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                  child: RotatedBox(
                    quarterTurns: -1,
                    child: Text("PLACES"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
                label: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                  child: RotatedBox(
                    quarterTurns: -1,
                    child: Text("EVENT"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(

                icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
                label: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                  child: RotatedBox(
                    quarterTurns: -1,
                    child: Text("FAVORITE"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
                label: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                  child: RotatedBox(
                    quarterTurns: -1,
                    child: Text("ACCOUNT"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
        if(_selectedIndex == 0) PlaceList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]

You can see its showing the active navigation color only. I want to show the others also i try to change the color but its invisible dont know what's the issue in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define the behavior of the labels of a NavigationRail you have to work with the `labelType`, there are four different constants you can use, to show the labels you can use the `all constant`, as follows:

```
NavigationRail(
          ...
          labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
          ...
          destinations: ...)
```

With that you will get the next result:

[image]

Hope it helps, for more info please check the [NavigationRailLabelType documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRailLabelType.html).